# How to keep the process in a simple animation with some time duration?

Tags: android

I want to change the imageview (x,y) values by using the setX(),setY(). It is directly going like an visible/gone. I just wants to keep this in a small animation so that it will go slowly to the given cordinates.

Is there any basic animation for performing this.

Comment: You can use move animation from this link : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/#move

Comment: I wants to dynamically change the positions using setX,setY

Answer (score 0):

You should use ObjectAnimator and AnimatorSet to achieve this.
Use Following code:

```
ObjectAnimator oaX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", 0, xValue);
oaX.setDuration(1000);
ObjectAnimator oaY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", 0, yValue);
oaY.setDuration(1000);
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.playTogether(oaX, oaY);
animatorSet.start();
```

pass your coordinate values to xValue and yValue, these are relative to your image's actual coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to move your imageview is here:

```
 imageview.animate().translationX(imageview.getWidth()).setDuration(1000).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
```

Comment: where should I give my new x,y values

Comment: If I wants to change the x value from 0 to 100 where should I give that

Comment: imageview.animate().translationY(imageview.getWidth()).setDuration(1000).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

Comment: you should give x value in  translationX and y value in translationY